# How to avoid type-checking of a subclass?

Tags: java, oop

I have this code:

```
public abstract class Character {
    public abstract void attack(Character victim);
    public abstract void receiveAttack(Attack attack);
}

public class CharacterA extends Character {
    public void attack(Character victim) {
        if (victim.getClass().equals(this.getClass())
            return;

        victim.receiveAttack(new Attack(BASE_DMG));
    }
}
```

The idea is that a Character can attack and receiveAttacks to/from other Characters, but it cannot receive an attack that comes from a character of its own class (CharacterA cannot attack another CharacterA but could attack CharacterB or receive an attack from a CharacterB).

I know that checking for the type of an object is a bad smell and is usually caused because of a bad design, so the question is how could I change the design so I don't have to check for the object type?

**EDIT**

The class is not actually named `Character`, the name is just to simplify the example.

There are no teams. `CharacterA` can attack any other `Character` that is not a `CharacterA`.

**FINAL EDIT**

Thanks everyone, I solved it by using the Visitor pattern.

Comment: I do not know whether your `CharacterA` and `CharacterB` are so different, that they need to be different implementation of the common ancestor, but i would use a property to distinguish them...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. They would implement their `attack` and `receiveAttack` methods in different ways. CharacterB may have armor so he would receive less damage and CharacterA may send an attack with a special effect. Even if I use a property (something like a State pattern), wouldn't I have to check for object type on that property?

Comment: If there are several subclasses of Character, and the general rule will always be that you can't attack something of your own class, then what you've done is perfectly fine, because you've encapsulated the rule in a single place.  By the way, things can go horribly wrong if you give one of your classes the same name as a class from `java.lang` - so please consider calling `Character` something different.

Comment: If the number of derived classes is finite, you can use the Visitor pattern.

Comment: You could also use "strategy" pattern for this.

Comment: @EJP Which pattern should OP use if the number of derived classes is infinite? :-)

Comment: What you did is fine, except that you probably dont need many specialized character classes.

Comment: Thanks for the Visitor pattern, I didn't know about it, I'll give it a try. @Usagi Miyamoto I don't really see how a Strategy pattern would solve this, could you please explain a little bit?

Comment: What's the purpose of `CharacterA` and `CharacterB`? Are they strictly for ensuring one character doesn't attack another? It could be enforced by the mediator that controls the characters, but you'll have to be more specific to get better answers. To me, it does sound like you're creating teams. Why else would you want to prevent attacking the same type of character?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution/ work-around could be to have only one class, and every `Character` Object has a `String` field named `characterTeam` or something of the like. For characters on the A team, set that field to `"A"` or `"ATeam"`. For B Team, set that field to `"B"` or `"BTeam"`. Then compare their `characterTeam` `String`s in the `attack` method.

Also, I would advise against having a class named `Character` as this might interfere with the wrapper class for `char`, also named `Character`.

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as checking for object type? I mean, I'd be using a conditional to check on something that tells me the type (instead of solving it by polymorphism or something in a OO-way). PS: The class is not actually named `Character`.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean in the last part of your comment. Would there not be any conflicts between a custom class named Character and the [java.lang.Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by adding an overloaded attack method to each subclass that's declared to take an instance of the specific subclass, and making this method a no-op, or printing a warning.

For CharacterA the signature would be

```
public void attack(CharacterA victim)
```

However, this will only work if your subclass instances are declared with the specific type, not the base Character type.

```
class Character
{
    public void attack(Character victim)
    {
        System.out.println(getClass() + " attacking " + victim.getClass());
        victim.receiveAttack(new Attack());
    }

    public void receiveAttack(Attack attack) {}
}

class CharacterA extends Character
{
    public void attack(CharacterA victim)
    {
        System.out.println(getClass() + " cannot attack " + victim.getClass());
    }
}

class CharacterB extends Character
{
    public void attack(CharacterB victim)
    {
        System.out.println(getClass() + " cannot attack " + victim.getClass());
    }
}

class Attack
{
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CharacterA a = new CharacterA();
        CharacterB b = new CharacterB();

        a.attack(a);
        a.attack(b);
        b.attack(a);
        b.attack(b);

        // redeclare a & b to have the base type
        Character c = a;
        Character d = b;

        c.attack(c);
        c.attack(d);
        d.attack(c);
        d.attack(d);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    class CharacterA cannot attack class CharacterA
    class CharacterA attacking class CharacterB
    class CharacterB attacking class CharacterA
    class CharacterB cannot attack class CharacterB
    class CharacterA attacking class CharacterA
    class CharacterA attacking class CharacterB
    class CharacterB attacking class CharacterA
    class CharacterB attacking class CharacterB
```

Comment: This would be a good solution if it worked for the base type. Except for the duplicated code in each Character.

Comment: That's a very bad solution because of type erasure at runtime in java. The fact that `Character a = new CharacterA();` vs `CharacterA a = new CharacterA();` changes the behavior of the program is very unexpected. You could use double-dispatch however, but without method overloading (Visitor pattern).